# Query current Flutter AppLifecycleState

Tags: flutter, dart

I am aware that we can observe [AppLifecycle state changes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html), but how can we query the current state?

I'd like to guard certain logic before it has observed a state change.

Comment: Maybe you can check with `this.mounted` in your Widget?

Comment: You could also create a base widget that observes and caches the lifecycle state.
Then derive from the base widget to query Lifecycle state.

Comment: @dumazy my `WidgetsBindingObserver` is a mixin on my custom `ChangeNotifier` (I'm using the Provider pattern) and it's not a Widget. As a result `this.mounted` is not available.

Comment: @Sakchham Yes but there is a tricky case where the first time you load the app, the `resumed` state is not caught as it happens before the WidgetsBindingObserver is added to be observed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit late, but as this was the first result on Google when I was querying the same thing, here's the answer:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.lifecycleState
```